# Left join of 2 exploded polars columns

Tags: python, left-join, python-polars, pandas-explode

##### Considering

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [
    [1, 2],
    [3]],
    "b": [
        [{"id": 1, "x": 1}, {"id": 3, "x": 3}],
        [{"id": 3, "x": 4}]]})
```

That looks like:

```
+------+---------------------+
|a     |b                    |
+------+---------------------+
|[1, 2]|[{1,1}, {3,3}]|
|[3]   |[{3,4}]              |
+------+---------------------+
```

##### How to

- get one row for each flatten `a` element and
- if the list of `dict` in `b` contains the `a` element as `id`
- then have the corresponding `x` value in the column `b`
- otherwise `b` should be `null`

---

##### Current approach

`.explode` both `a` and `b` and `.filter` (INNER JOIN):

```
df.explode("a").explode("b").filter(
    pl.col("a") == pl.col("b").struct.field('id')
).select(
    pl.col("a"),
    pl.col("b").struct.field("x")
)
```

Unfortunately I get only the (expected):

```
+-+----+
|a|b   |
+-+----+
|1|1   |
|3|4   |
+-+----+
```

Instead of the full "LEFT JOIN" I am aiming to:

```
+-+----+
|a|b   |
+-+----+
|1|1   |
|2|null|
|3|4   |
+-+----+
```

How to efficiently get the desired result when the DataFrame is structured like that?

Comment: Is it considered a "match" if *any* dict in *b* contains the value of *a* as *id*? Or must it be the dict at the same index as the element in the list of *a*?

Comment: @Hericks every row has different dict on the `b` column. On the `b` column there will be only one match, all the time. I would consider those dicts like key-value tuples of a dict for each original row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned it, you can also use a left-join explicitly:

```py
df_a = df.explode("a")
df_b = df_a.explode("b").unnest("b").filter(pl.col("a") == pl.col("id"))

df_a.select("a").join(df_b, on="a", how="left")
```

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ id   ┆ x    │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1    ┆ 1    │
│ 2   ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 3   ┆ 3    ┆ 4    │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

With regards to your current filtering logic:

You want to pick a single row if there are no matches per group e.g.

```py
is_id = pl.col("a") == pl.col("id")

is_id | (is_id.not_().all().over("a") & pl.col("a").is_first_distinct())
```

But it's quite awkward and you still have to null out the non-matches in an extra step.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I am gonna use this solution as the real table has way more columns, so the grouping from the other solution would be a little unpractical.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following.

1. Explode columns `a` and `b` separately.
2. Unnest column `b` into columns `id` and `x`.
3. For each group defined by `a`, compute the corresponding value of `x` as follows.

   - `pl.when(pl.col("a") == pl.col("id")).then("x")` contains `x`, if `a` matches `id`, and `None` otherwise (still multiple values within each group).
   - [`pl.Expr.sort`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.sort.html) sorts these values and place null-values first.
   - Hence, [`pl.Expr.last`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.last.html) selects the non-null value if it exists and `None` otherwise.

```py
(
    df
    .explode("a").explode("b").unnest("b")
    .group_by("a", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.when(pl.col("a") == pl.col("id")).then("x").sort().last()
    )
)
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ x    │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1    │
│ 2   ┆ null │
│ 3   ┆ 4    │
└─────┴──────┘
```